# Flask, wsgi and deploy

Tags: python, flask

(pardon my english)
Hello,

I've a problem for a deploy on a gandi server.

After a git push on a gandi server, I'm proceeding a deploy :

```
ssh [url] deploy default.git
```

I obtain an "Internal Error Server".

My log/www/uwsgi.log said :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from run import app as application
  File "./run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app as application
  File "./app/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    _patch_async()
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 78, in _patch_async
    from jinja2.asyncsupport import patch_all
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 13, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "/opt/python-3.6/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "/opt/python-3.6/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 17, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
  File "/opt/python-3.6/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
  File "/opt/python-3.6/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 55, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.connection import wait
  File "/opt/python-3.6/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import util
  File "/opt/python-3.6/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 17, in <module>
    from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
  File "/opt/python-3.6/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 136, in <module>
    import _posixsubprocess
ImportError: /srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _Py_set_inheritable_async_safe
```

I have not idea how can I solve this problem... ?

Anyone understand this problem ? Thank you

Comment: Up. I don't find a solution since several days and I'm really tired for this error !